# WCF Service for HTML5 and Silverlight

Tags: wcf

My WCF service has two endpoints(Normal and REST, one for Silverlight client and other for HTML5 client) and my Silverlight client application works perfectly without any issues. When I open my service in the IE, I am getting HTTP 400 bad request. It looks like REST part of my service has some issue. I have given both end points below. Appreciate any help!

Normal end point

```
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Test.Service1"
              bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_Config"
              behaviorConfiguration="MessageInspectorEndpointBehavior">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
```

WCF end point

```
    <endpoint address="rest" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Test.Service1"
      behaviorConfiguration="web">
    </endpoint>
```

Comment: Without more information about the contract, the request or the actual error (Which can be found by enabling tracing), it'd be really hard to figure out why the server is rejecting the request.

Comment: How to enable tracing? Can you please point me to some links?

Comment: The first three links at http://www.bing.com/search?q=wcf+enable+tracing are a good start.

Comment: I enabled tracing, no log is being created when I try to open the service in the IE. I just type as shown below. just trying to browse the service in IE.  http://localhost:1706/WCF/Test/Service1.svc

Comment: Make sure that the directory where the log file is being written has write access for the account used by IIS (usually "NETWORK SERVICE"). Also, it's always good to always flush the trace (add `<trace autoflush='true'/>` under `<system.diagnostics>` to prevent IIS from buffering any issues which can point to the problem.

Comment: Thanks, the log file is created. The file has an exception and here is the message. 'There is a problem with the XML that was received from the network. See inner exception for more details'.  Please let me know what to look for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request should be made to .../WCF/Test/Service1.svc/**rest**, since this is the address for the REST endpoint you added in config.